# Rational roots theorem on a polynomial with coefficients rationals.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to apply  rational roots theorem to a polynomial with rational coefficients?

By example, if ($a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i\neq j)$
\begin{eqnarray}
p(x)&=&\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i\\
&=&\sum_{i=0,i\neq j}^{n} a_ix^i+(b/c)x^j,\quad (a_j=b/c\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus{\mathbb{Z}})
\end{eqnarray}
Now, let $q(x)=cp(x)=\sum_{i=0,i\neq j}^{n} ca_ix^i+(b)x^j$. Suposse that, by Rational roots theorem, $q(x)$ has a rational root $r$. Then $q(r)=0$ implies $p(r)=0$.

Therefore $r$ is also a rational root for $p$
This is correct? or exists a counterexample.

Comment: "by Rational roots theorem, $q(x)$ has a rational root $r$"?  No, the rational root theorem never says that a polynomial **has** a rational root.  It restricts the possibilities for rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: I know that, but in the case that there is indeed a rational root for $q (x)$. This will also be the rational root for $p (x)$ or not?

Comment: If you have a polynomial with rational coefficients, you can multiply by the lcm of the denominators of those coefficients to get a polynomial with integer coefficients, and apply the rational roots theorem to that.  It is true that the original polynomial and the new polynomial have the same roots.

Comment: That was my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you already found the answer to your question, you may want to self-answer your question and accept it afterwards to remove it from the [Unanswered](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) tab. Or you can ask @RobertIsrael to post their comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a polynomial with rational coefficients, you can multiply by the lcm of the denominators of those coefficients to get a polynomial with integer coefficients, and apply the rational roots theorem to that. It is true that the original polynomial and the new polynomial have the same roots. – Robert Israel

Thanks!